# Return to a Dialog within Task<DialogTurnResult>

Tags: c#, botframework

I have specific dialogs within Task function. Is there a way to return to a certain dialog within the Task without exiting out of the waterfall step.

Thank you

I've tried cs.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] = (int)cs.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"] -1; to return to the previous dialog state but it executes the next waterfall dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the most common approach is to replace the current dialog with itself, adding logic to each waterfall step as to if it should execute or drop through to the next step.  For example, you should set the step index you want to execute from in the dialog options and then check to see if this value is set as each step is executed.

e.g. as simplified version of a waterfall step here might look like the following;

When you want to go back to a previous step you can use;

```cs
            return await sc.ReplaceDialogAsync(YourCurrentDialogID, new YourCurrentDialog(stepIndexToGoBackTo));
```

then in each waterfall step you can check to see if you have specified a particular step to jump back to, if not it executes each step sequentially.

```cs
        public async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptUser(WaterfallStepContext sc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var stepToExecute = sc.Options as int?;

            if(!stepToExecute.HasValue || (stepToExecute.HasValue && stepToExecute.Value == sc.Index)
{
    // either we haven't set a specific step to run, so we will execute anyway
    // or we have specified a step to run and the index matches, so we conditionally execute
}

// a step index has been passed into the options, but it doesn't match the current step
// so drop through until we hit the right step.
return await sc.NextAsync();
}
```

Please excuse the code above, it may not complie exactly, but it should be about right. I am writing this on a mobile :)

Comment: Thank you for this Sir. However, I have specified specific cases within my Waterfall Step. Will this still be possible despite the cases?